# How to Add Tuples of Two into a Dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I have two lists:

```
list1 = ['USD', 'GBP', 'CHF', 'HRK', 'HUF', 'RSD', 'BAM', 'MKD', 'RUB', 'CZK', 'PLN', 'BGN', 'NOK', 'SEK', 'DKK', 'AUD', 'CAD', 'JPY']

list2 = [('1,0748', '1,0508'), ('0,8639', '0,8399'), ('1,0942', '1,0602'), ('7,6508', '7,4208'), ('5,8900', '7,0900'), ('4,9400', '1,1400'), ('1,9850', '1,9190'), ('2,1100', '0,2900'), ('1,9393', '6,5393'), ('7,5440', '6,5440'), ('4,5090', '4,3610'), ('1,9790', '1,9250'), ('9,2471', '8,9071'), ('9,9290', '9,6090'), ('7,5521', '7,3281'), ('1,4444', '1,4004'), ('1,4528', '1,4048'), ('1,8300', '8,0300')]
```

How would I make a dictionary, where the two item tuples would be the values and the items in list1 keys to those tuples.

Something like this: `{'USD': (1.0748, 1.0508), 'GBP': (0.8639, 0.8399), etc.}.`

The first item from list one goes with the first tuple from list2, the second with the second, etc.

Also, as you can see, the "numbers" are strings in list2, but become floats in the dictionary. How could this be done in the easiest way possible?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Crude way of doing it: `d = {i:(float(j[0].replace(',', '.')),float(j[1].replace(',', '.'))) for i,j in zip(list1, list2)}`

Comment: @Farhan.K: if that's meant to be a solution to the OP's problem and we're not closing the question, why is it a comment and not an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first transform the values from string to floats with a comprehension:

```
f_list2 = [tuple(map(float, [i.replace(',','.'), j.replace(',','.')])) for (i,j) in list2]
```

this just goes through every subelement in every tuple replacing occurences of `','` with `'.'` and makes them `float`s by use of `map`; wrapping the `map` result in a `tuple` expands it and retains the elements inside tuples as they originally were.

and then use `zip` to pass the pairs to `dict`. `dict` also accepts tuple pairs `(key, val)` that it uses to initialize `key` and `value` accordingly. So:

```
d = dict(zip(list1, f_list2))
```

With `d` now having the contents:

```
{'AUD': (1.4444, 1.4004),
 'BAM': (1.985, 1.919),
 'BGN': (1.979, 1.925),
 'CAD': (1.4528, 1.4048),
 'CHF': (1.0942, 1.0602),
 'CZK': (7.544, 6.544),
 'DKK': (7.5521, 7.3281),
 'GBP': (0.8639, 0.8399),
 'HRK': (7.6508, 7.4208),
 'HUF': (5.89, 7.09),
 'JPY': (1.83, 8.03),
 'MKD': (2.11, 0.29),
 'NOK': (9.2471, 8.9071),
 'PLN': (4.509, 4.361),
 'RSD': (4.94, 1.14),
 'RUB': (1.9393, 6.5393),
 'SEK': (9.929, 9.609),
 'USD': (1.0748, 1.0508)}
```

Comment: If this were the answer we should close this question as a dup.  But the question has a second component as well, involving converting from commas-as-decimal-marker strings to floats.

Answer (score 0):

regex way of doing it

```
list1 = ['USD', 'GBP', 'CHF', 'HRK', 'HUF', 'RSD', 'BAM', 'MKD', 'RUB', 'CZK', 'PLN', 'BGN', 'NOK', 'SEK', 'DKK', 'AUD', 'CAD', 'JPY']
list2 = [('1,0748', '1,0508'), ('0,8639', '0,8399'), ('1,0942', '1,0602'), ('7,6508', '7,4208'), ('5,8900', '7,0900'), ('4,9400', '1,1400'), ('1,9850', '1,9190'), ('2,1100', '0,2900'), ('1,9393', '6,5393'), ('7,5440', '6,5440'), ('4,5090', '4,3610'), ('1,9790', '1,9250'), ('9,2471', '8,9071'), ('9,9290', '9,6090'), ('7,5521', '7,3281'), ('1,4444', '1,4004'), ('1,4528', '1,4048'), ('1,8300', '8,0300')]
import re
d = dict(zip( list1, eval( re.sub("'(\d+),(\d+)'", r'\1.\2', str(list2)) ) ))
# replace eval with ast.literal_eval if the source of list2 might be dangerous
```